# Redirect urls containing rogue characters

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have some crawl errors on our site and I'm trying to write a rewrite rule to fix them. What I want to say is that any url which begins with http://www.mysite.com/co that it should be redirected to a single url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^co http://www.othersite.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

However, this doesn't work for the following urls

http://www.mysite.com/community/membe%3Cbr%3E%3Chr%3EタグOKです。%3Cbr%3E%3Ctextarea%20name=

http://www.mysite.com/community/membe%3Cbr%3E%3Chr%3E%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0OK%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%3Cbr%3E%3Ctextarea%20name=

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks

James

Comment: Do you have japanese characters in the URL?

Comment: Some of them do seem to have - there's a combination of incoming links from other sites which are malformed. I just want to redirect them all to a different site

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way would be whitelisting - redirect anything which contains characters not on *your* list of allowed characters. In this example, let's say you'd allow only lowercase letters, number 4, and the slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule [^a-z4/] http://example.com/redirect-to-here [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's a good idea but how would I write the rule such that it only applies to urls which begin with "/co"? I don't want to apply the rule to the whole website